# Leaflet: change the div in which the map renders to dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I am developing a leaflet application using react. My issue is that every time the route remounts the leaflet map does not render unless the page is reloaded. I assume because the div it is tied to is removed from the DOM and then re-added.

I have the map object stored and I am wondering if there is a way to set it to render to a new div element dynamically without reloading the page.

Here is the component class.

```
export default class Map extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    towerStore.addListener("added", this.handleAddedTower);
    towerStore.addListener("removed", this.handleRemovedTower);
    towerStore.addListener("updated", this.handleUpdatedTower);
    MapActions.createMap();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    towerStore.removeListener("added", this.handleAddedTower);
    towerStore.removeListener("removed", this.handleRemovedTower);
    towerStore.removeListener("updated", this.handleUpdatedTower);
  }

  handleAddedTower = e => {
    MapActions.plotTower(e);
  };
  handleRemovedTower = e => {
    MapActions.removeTower(e);
  };
  handleUpdatedTower = e => {
    MapActions.updateTower(e);
  };

  render() {
    return (

      <div id="map-container">
        <div id="map" />
        <MapControls />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the createMap function.

```
mapCreated = false;
exports.createMap = () => {
  if (!mapCreated) {
    console.log("creating map");

    map = L.map("map", {
      zoom: 10,
      // minZoom:10,
      // maxZoom:16,
      // zoomSnap: 2,
      center: [49.528528, -96.691092],
      zoomControl: false,
      attributionControl: false,
      doubleClickZoom: false,
      boxZoom: false
    });

    L.tileLayer("https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      crossOrigin: true
    }).addTo(map);

    exports.goToLocation();

    mapCreated = true;
  }
};
```

Comment: Some code sample would be helpful.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the existing Leaflet components fro react?

Comment: I was not aware there were any. Would you be able to point me to the git repository? @IvanSanchez

Comment: Not really, because it's better to point you at the list at http://leafletjs.com/plugins#frameworks--build-systems ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer to this and is not aware of leaflet plugins, IvanSanchez has the best solution which is to use the React-Leaflet plugin found here http://leafletjs.com/plugins#frameworks.